# How to constrain a stack view to top portion of screen? Using storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I have a stack view that I want on the top third of the screen, even with different screen sizes.

I tried adding:

- horizontal and vertical constraints

[image]

But the results aren't going as expected
[image]

Ideally I'd like all screens to look like the one on the right. Just a little bit of space between the top. (which is why I'm not using the constant number. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey keep the constraints in the storyboards as it is and create a outlet of the stack and add the following code in viewdidload

```
 //Assuming that your outlet would be named stackView
  
  let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: (-view.frame.size.height / 4))

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([yConstraint])
```

this will place your stackView in the first half of your screen just like you wanted , let me know how this goes for you